# Creating new layer with custom regions from states boundaries in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, dissolve, united-states

I am trying to create a map where I can combine a layer of states boundaries and one other with custom regions (Est/West) on QGIS.

So I have tried it in different ways (union, intersection, merge layers) but without success.

Here's the result I would like to have but in a single layer.

[image]

As you can see I have two layers, one for the boundaries of the region and one for the states.

I would like to create a new layer with both of them.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Use the Dissolve Tool:  Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Dissolve

Comment: What does not work with  `merge vector layers` ? which is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Dissolve

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The OP wanted one layer - maybe add steps describing Merge Vector Layers as hinted by @Kasper ?